# Assume that the order of $a$ modulo $n$ is $h$ and the order of $b$ modulo $n$ is $k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume that the order of $a$ modulo $n$ is $h$ and the order of $b$ modulo $n$ is $k$. 
Show that the order of $ab$ modulo $n$ divides $hk$; in particular, if $\gcd(h, k) = 1$, then $ab$ has order $hk$.

My attempt :

$$(ab)^{hk}\equiv  1\pmod{n} \implies \text{ord}_n(ab) | hk$$

But I feel stuck at showing that  if $\gcd(h, k) = 1$, then $ab$ has order $hk$. Do I get any help ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If ord$_na=h,$ord$_nb=k$ with $(h,k)=1$

If ord$_n(ab)=d\implies (ab)^d\equiv1$

$\implies a^{hd}b^{hd}=\left[(ab)^d\right]^h\equiv1\implies b^{hd}\equiv1\implies k|hd$

As $(h,k)=1,k|d$

Similarly, $h|d\implies$lcm$[h,k]|d\implies hk|d\  \ \  \ (1)$  as  $(h,k)=1$

Now $(ab)^{hk}=(a^h)^k(b^k)^h\equiv1\pmod n\implies d|hk\ \ \ \ (2)$

Can you combine $(1),(2)?$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ \color{#c00}{a^{\large h}}\equiv 1\equiv\color{#0a0}{b^{\large k}}\,\Rightarrow\, (ab)^{\large hk} \equiv (\color{#c00}{a^{\large h}})^{\large k}(\color{#0a0}{b^{\large k}})^{\large h}\equiv \color{#c00}1^{\large k}\color{#0a0}1^{\large h}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm ord}(ab)\mid hk$